# Rails: self join scheme with has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-join

I would like to create a structure of `Users` having many `friends`, also of class `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: "User"
end
```

I do not need any details of their relationship thus I do not use `:through` with kind of class `Friendship`. But now I cannot find any way how to create corresponding database (neither with migration file nor using `rails g model User username:string ...` command). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I do not need any details of their relationship". Do you mean you simply want to get back an array of `User` objects?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to connect them directly, not through another class.

Answer (score 39):

Here are some resources which may be helpful:

- [RailsCasts episode #163 Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast) regarding self-referential many-to-many relationships
- [RailsCasts episode #47 Two Many-to-Many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many). This might be more relevant to what you're attempting to accomplish
- [A gist someone created for self-referential relationships using HABTM](https://gist.github.com/srpouyet/4121517)

I'll summarize the information found in those links:

Given that you're describing a self-referential many-to-many relationship, you will of course end up with a join table. Normally, the join table should be deliberately named in such a way that Rails will automatically figure out which models the table is joining, however the "self-referential" part makes this a tad awkward, but not difficult. You'll merely have to specify the name of the join table, as well as the joining columns.

You'll need to create this table using a migration that will probably look something like this:

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :friendships, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_user_id
    end

    add_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_user_id], :unique => true)
    add_index(:friendships, [:friend_user_id, :user_id], :unique => true)
  end

  def self.down
      remove_index(:friendships, [:friend_user_id, :user_id])
      remove_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_user_id])
      drop_table :friendships
  end
end
```

I'm not certain whether there is a shortcut way of creating this table, but bare minimum you can simply do `rails g migration create_friendships`, and fill in the `self.up` and `self.down` methods.

And then finally in your user model, you simply add the name of the join table, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, 
              class_name: "User", 
              join_table: :friendships, 
              foreign_key: :user_id, 
              association_foreign_key: :friend_user_id
end
```

As you can see, while you do have a join table in the database, there is no related join model.

Please let me know whether this works for you.

Comment: Could you explain the reason behind adding two indexes with `:user_id` and `:friend_user_id` in different order?
Why not only one index?

Comment: "A gist someone created for self-referential relationships using HABTM" returns a 404 on Github.

Comment: The two indexes are for uniqueness in each direction, bob has a friendship with alice, but maybe alice doesn't have a friendship with bob, but bob can't have multiple friendships with alice, and alice can't have multiple friendships with bob.

Comment: @Joe but since they're different indexes, do they really solve the issue that there might be a friendship(user_id=<bob>, friend_id=<alice>) and another one friendship(user_id=<alice>, friend_id=<alice>)? Semantically, this shouldn't be possible (they're the same friendship), but these two indexes allow that to happen.