# Has_and_belong_to_many relation with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to implement a `has_and_belong_to_many` relation with the same model, but I don't know how.

For Example, a user should be able to follow other users.

Also, I have multiple fields of the same model in that model; how would I give it another name?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770888/rails-self-join-scheme-with-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: @steveklein rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios and two different implementations:

---

### The 'Friends' model

Let's say one `User` can have many `:friends` where each friend is also an object of the `User` model. You can do it this way:

```rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: 'User'
```

This tells rails that an object of `User` class can have a many-to-many relation with itself as `friends`. So you can call something like this:

```
@user_a.friends
#=> [@user_x, @user_y, @user_z]  # Array of User Objects

@user_x.friends
#=> [@user_a, @user_b, @user_c]  # Array of User Objects
```

---

### The 'Followers/Following' model

Let's say one `User` can follow other users as well have other users follow him. This is how you'll implement it:

```rb
has_many   :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following
belongs_to :following, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers
```

This tells rails that each user can have many `followers` which is an Array of other `User` objects, and that user is accessible to others as an object in the `following` array. For example, if `@user2` follows `@user1`, it would look like this:

```
@user1.followers
#=> [@user2, @user3]

@user2.following
#=> [@user1]
```

Comment: I always got stuck with `inverse_of` options... can you clarify what it does ?

Comment: +1 for more details. Still what technically `inverse_of` option does there? Anything kind of _caching_... ? Got the answer, it is [optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296694/what-does-inverse-of-do-what-sql-does-it-generate).

Comment: Why don't need to mention _foreign_key_ here ?

Comment: Multiple ways of doing the same thing... We don't need to specify it _explicitly_ here, since we're already using `inverse_of`. If we use `foreign_key` instead, we'll have to change `following` to `following_ids`. I think the `inverse_of` approach looks cleaner.

Comment: RoR [Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has a lot more information on this.

Comment: I read the guide. But it looks experienced eyes sometime to understand what they meant.. I am away now from those eyes.. anyway thanks for those replies...