# Rails association with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am bit confused with these issue

Here is the Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :true_items, :foreign_key => "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is the TrueItem  model

```
class TrueItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Item"
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Here am taking all the items includes true_items

```
items = Item.includes(:true_items)
items.each do |item|
   item.true_items.each do | true_item |
      true_items = "#{true_item.item.name}"
   end
end
```

Here the problem is, when i am taking the item.name like "#{true_item.item.name}" in the loop, duplicate query happening, that means again calling that item get the name. is there any issue with that association?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you have two associations, to `parent` and to `item`.

You could just call the right association in your loop:

```
Item.includes(:true_items).each do |item|
   item.true_items.each do |true_item|
      true_items = "#{true_item.parent.name}"
   end
end
```

Or you could actually just add an alias to your association (since `item` and `parent` is actually the same association):

```
class TrueItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Item"
  alias_attribute :item, :parent
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but is not avoiding the duplication

Comment: Also i cannot use parent.item, because the item and parent is different, here i am taking TrueItem name, but when we use the parent, its giving from the table (Item).name

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :true_items,
        class_name: "Item", 
        join_table: :true_items, 
        foreign_key: :item_id, 
        association_foreign_key: :true_item_id
end
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770888/rails-self-join-scheme-with-has-and-belongs-to-many)

This will allow you to call the following:

```
<% @items = Item.all %>
<% @items.each do |item| %> 
   <% item.true_items.each do |true_item| %>
      <%= true_item.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You'll even be able to keep your `true_items` table (you may have to remove the `id`, `created_at` & `updated_at` fields.