# ruby on rails: hierarchy model with multiple parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I'm currently using ancestry gem to do a hierarchy list of my "posts", but I need to have the option to a child have multiple parents, and with ancestry I can't do that. You guys have any solution? Adapting ancestry with other gem or using other gem instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Use HABATM association

What you want to achieve is essentially [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship. You can create a relationship on yourself and that should do the trick. If you need help on how to do this with HABTM association, [here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19773229/52317) that shows how.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children, 
              class_name: "Post", 
              join_table: :children, 
              foreign_key: :post_id, 
              association_foreign_key: :child_post_id
end
```

---

### Alternatively, use a gem

You can use [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem to tag your posts. It would be better if you create a model or enum that holds your tags, so that you don't mistype them while tagging.

You can query your posts like this:

```
Post.tagged_with(["ruby", "rails"], :any => true)
```

Comment: this is for a single table?

Comment: Yeap, it is for a single table.