# has_many :through with multiple sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model named `AnswerConnection`, who has two foreign keys from `Answer` model: `answer_1` and `answer_2`.

In my `Answer` model I have defined:

`has_many :connections, through: :answer_connections, source: :answer_2`

However, the relationship is simmetrycal: if answer_1 is connected to answer_2, answer_2 is connected to answer_1. This means that when I search the connections of an specific answer, I need to check if its present in answer_1 or answer_2 field.

There is possible to define a relationship attending this (like if I could define two values in `:source` parameter)?

Comment: sounds like you want to use has_and_belongs_to_many, or possibly has_many_through if you want to put other fields in your AnswerConnection model

Comment: Yes, My `Answer` model have a `has many through` relationship with `AnswerConnection` model. However, from my Answer model I would like to get its connections, respecting this simmetrycal relationship described.

Comment: oh sorry, I missed the crucial point that it's a self reference association.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770888/rails-self-join-scheme-with-has-and-belongs-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set 2 sources, but if I understood it correctly you could do something like:

```
has_many :connections_1, through: :answer_connections, source: :answer_1
has_many :connections_2, through: :answer_connections, source: :answer_2

def connections
  connections_1.merge(connections_2) # intersection
  # or connections_1.or(connections_2) for union
end
```

Comment: Please note that while this efficiently gives you a combined list, other operations (eg removing a connection) will still require extra code.  So depending on future needs, even though this looks simpler than the answer I linked to above where all connection are automatically recorded both ways--it could well end up being more complicated in the end.

Comment: This answer is giving me a multiple association error on the Inner Join, any ideas? `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "connections" specified more than once`