# Ruby on Rails: has_many self join

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through, has-many

Rails 5.

I have been trying to create a self referencing has_many relationship based on this tutorial:  https://medium.com/@jbmilgrom/active-record-many-to-many-self-join-table-e0992c27c1e (the last piece: Has_many | Has_many — Self Join Table)

I also see various threads here about this concept but I'm still a little lost when it comes to my problem and its terminology. And I am not sure what the database should look like. I should also mention that I am very new to Rails.

I am trying to create 'representative' - 'represented' relationship between Users.

A User can be represented by many Users (User has_many Representatives).
And a User can represent many Users (User has_many Represented).

Based on the tutorial in the link above I wrote my User model like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :representatives, through: :representive_link, source: :representative
  has_many :representive_link, foreign_key: :represented_user_id, class_name: 'representatives'

  has_many :represented, through: :represented_link, source: :represented
  has_many :represented_link, foreign_key: :representative_user_id, class_name: 'representatives'
end
```

Then I created a representatives table like so (I called it representatives but its really the group of representatives and represented):

```
class Representatives < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :representative, foreign_key: 'representative_user_id', class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :represented, foreign_key: 'represented_user_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

I also created a representatives table in the database which looks like this:

```
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| representive_user_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| represented_user_id  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at           | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at           | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So, In the Rails console I create two users:

```
u1 = User.create('id' => 1, 'username' => 'john')
u2 = User.create('id' => 2, 'username' => 'mike')
```

I want u2 to represent u1:

```
u1.representatives = [u2]
```

But I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::representatives
```

I'm finding this concept quite confusing and the other threads here don't clear it up for me. Can someone break this concept down in relation to my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: self join scheme with has\_and\_belongs\_to\_many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770888/rails-self-join-scheme-with-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the end I got it to work with some slight modification. First I renamed some things to make it make a little more sense (if only in my head).

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :represented_link, foreign_key: :representative_id, class_name: 'RepresentativeGrouping'
  has_many :represented, through: :represented_link, source: :represented

  has_many :representive_link, foreign_key: :represented_id, class_name: 'RepresentativeGrouping'
  has_many :representatives, through: :representive_link, source: :representative
end
```

RepresentativeGrouping model:

```
class RepresentativeGrouping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :representative, foreign_key: 'representative_id', class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :represented, foreign_key: 'represented_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

the representative_grouping table:

```
mysql> describe representative_groupings;
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| representative_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| represented_id    | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

One thing that is vital here is the arrangement of the has _many definitions in the User model. In the question about you'll see that the has_many definition with the through: and source: in it was below the has_many definition with the class_name: and foreign_key:. After I had changed the names around I got passed my first error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::representatives
```

But moved on to another error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#representatives' which goes through 'User#representive_link' before the through association is defined.
```

googling led me to here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29123, where someone mentioned the issue with the arrangement of the definitions, and that you must have them in the reverse of my order.

After these changes I was able to run code like this:

```
u1 = User.create(:id => 1, :username => 'john')
u2 = User.create(:id => 2, :username => 'mike')

u1.representatives = [u2]
puts u1.representatives

### displays u2's data

puts u2.represented

### displays u1's data
```

Answer (score 0):

In UserModel

To get **representatives** - 

`has_and_belongs_to_many :representatives, 
   class_name: "User",
   join_table: : representative_groupings,
   foreign_key: :represented_id,
   association_foreign_key: : representative_id`

To get **represented_by** - 

`has_and_belongs_to_many : represented,
   class_name: "User",
   join_table: : representative_groupings,
   foreign_key: :representative_id,
   association_foreign_key: : represented_id`

> This also eliminates the need for your explicit model ***rails*** -
>    RepresentativeGrouping